# action script 2 versus action script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript-2

I am learning ActionScript and am brand new to making Flash movie clips.  Overall it seems pretty easy but I have discovered that there is a huge difference between AS2 and AS3, and that components built in one will not run with code written in the other.

This makes for some big obstacles for me, I have a reason to develop in AS2 but everything on the net is geared around AS3, even the latest versions of Flash Professional are full of components and examples in AS3.  (I am using CS5 right now).  I tried to use the components from the library and they do not work when building an AS2 project, the compiler errors all complain about "The class or interface 'xxx' could not be loaded" where xxx is referring to some part of the component object from the library.

Any advice here would be much appreciated.  I am sure experienced developers have had issues when trying to 'bridge the gap' between old code and new code, if there is a web resource or some sort of advice then that would help.

Comment: AS2 is ancient, not sure why you'd want to develop in it?  This question however, is not on-topic here.

Comment: Following up... I have a reason to develop in AS2, as in the class that will bind my variables to the program I am developing for was an AS2 class.  I don't think I can extend this class using AS3 code and expect it to work.. but there must be some workaround.

Comment: You should probably remake the classes. Actionscript 3 is better than Actionscript 2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActionScript

Answer (score 0):

Well, AS3 was introduced 9 Years ago! AS2 is deprecated and you really should write any code in AS3 for serveral reasons. The mysterious AS2 class that you need, may exist in AS3 or can be somehow adapted to AS3, if you tell us more about it maybe you get a proper solution.